# DataGridView resets Scroll&Select on Update

Tags: c#, winforms, select, datagridview, scrollbar

I have a problem with my datagridview: when i update my datagridview with BindingSource.ResetBindings(false) it drops select on my cells and drops scrollbar to the beginning.

I tried to save selected cells to temp and then try select them again, but if I keep mouse button pressed then, when I refresh table, selections zone start cells moves to beginning.

And I tried to save scrollbars states with saving DGV.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex and DGV.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex but it doesn't work very smooth.

Does somebody know more elegant solution?

Current Solution:

```
    private List<Cell> selectedCells;
    private Cell ShowCell;
    public void SaveSelections(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        if (dgv.Rows.Count == 0) return;
        ShowCell = new Cell(dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex, dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex);
        selectedCells = new List<Cell>();
        foreach (DataGridViewCell c in dgv.SelectedCells)
        {
            selectedCells.Add(new Cell(c.ColumnIndex, c.RowIndex));
        }
    }

    public void LoadSelections(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        if (dgv.Rows.Count == 0 || ShowCell == null) return;
        dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = ShowCell.Row;
        dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex = ShowCell.Column;
        dgv[0, 0].Selected = false;
        foreach (Cell c in selectedCells)
        {
            dgv[c.Column, c.Row].Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

It doesn't work smooth and elegent, scrollbars are always twitching and multi-select doesn't work correctly if selecting cells and update happens in the same time

Comment: saving the indices and use `FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex` and `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` after updating should work. You should show your actual code.